# Authenticate return value

Tags: login, wp-error

I am trying to hook into the *authenticate* return value to display error message on custom login form. The `$user` object is not returned.

```
add_action( 'authenticate', 'my_login_check' );
function my_login_check( $user ){
    if( is_wp_error( $user ) ){
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: try `add_filter('authenticate', 'my_login_check', 9999, 1);`

Comment: Do you mean that `$user` is not passed into `my_login_check`? Or that it is not returned from that function? If the latter, that is because you haven't `return`ed it.

Comment: I think you are using the wrong hook.  The 'authenticate' hook is for authenticating the user - meaning you take the information passed by the hook via parameters and return a WP_User object.  If the $user parameter is empty or !is_a($user, 'WP_User'), that means that the user has failed authenticating via other authentication methods.

Comment: It sounds like you might want to use the hook 'wp_signon' - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon